# How to load Sprites[] from Resources folder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 2D game in Unity.

Made a kind of hierarchy in my project directory and found a problem with loading array(or list, whatever) of Sprites from **Resources** folder.

Directory:

```
Resources/
  rew1.png
    rew1(Sprite)
  rew2.png
    rew2(Sprite)
```

I found a lot of posts about how to load only one sprite, but I want to make it "easy to add".

Can someone explain me how to do this?

1. Given: Directory name in **Resources** folder.
2. What to do: get and load all sprites from the directory.

**NOTE:** btw, I can't post picture of my folder, due to the requirement 10+ reputation on stackoverflow :(

Comment: But you can post some code with what you have tried so far and where it fails ;)

Comment: @Johan I fount the decision xD omg, that always happened, when I write or tell to someone about the problem.
var sps = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Sprites/profile/Reward");

         Debug.Log(sps == null ? "sps == null" : "sps != null");

         foreach (var sprite in sps)
         {
                Debug.Log(sprite.name);
         }

         this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sps[1];

Comment: Maybe that's because it it helpful to see some code in order to help a person faster and possibly point out some easy to spot mistake using the "4 eye principle"

Comment: _"I can't post picture of my folder, due to the requirement 10+ reputation"_ - just include the URL in your question and someone will fix it for you :)

Comment: @MickyDuncan heh, thx, first day here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try like:

```
Sprite[] sprites = (Sprite[])Resources.LoadAll(@"FolderName" + System.IO.Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar + imageName));
```

It is expecting that all the sprites are under `Resources\FolderName\` and `imageName` can be for example `a.png` So it will look like:

`Resources\FolderName\a.png`

**EDIT: **

```
Sprite sprites = Resources.Load<Sprite>(@"FolderName" + System.IO.Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar + imageName));
```

Comment: I want to know, does it affect memeroy hard? Cuz if there will be 1000+ sprites(theoretically), this code will load all of this 1000 sprites in memory?
Well, if I want only to get names, then find one I'm looking for, and load only one sprite.

Comment: Yes it will affect, you can also find just one sprite as well.

Comment: Indeed, using a spritesheet would be a much better idea if you are going to be using 1000+ sprites

Answer (score 0):

A small file utility class for Unity written by mstevenson. Transform an absolute path into an Assets folder relative path, and get a list of all Resources directories in the project. . [FileUtility.cs](https://gist.github.com/mstevenson/4386682)

Comment: Thank u a lot! That was directly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Kamiky please mark the best answer as "Accepted" so that people searching for the same solution in the future will find it quickly and other respondents can focus on other unanswered questions. Thanks!